# substring characters from a column in a data.table in R

Tags: regex, r, data.table

Is there a more "r" way to substring two meaningful characters out of a longer string from a column in a data.table?

I have a data.table that has a column with "degree strings"... shorthand code for the degree someone got and the year they graduated.

```
> srcDT<- data.table(
    alum=c("Paul Lennon","Stevadora Nicks","Fred Murcury"),
    degree=c("W72","WG95","W88")
    )

> srcDT
               alum degree
1:      Paul Lennon    W72
2:  Stevadora Nicks   WG95
3:     Fred Murcury    W88
```

I need to extract the digits of the year from the degree, and put it in a new column called "degree_year"

No problem:

```
> srcDT[,degree_year:=substr(degree,nchar(degree)-1,nchar(degree))]

> srcDT
                alum degree degree_year
 1:      Paul Lennon    W72          72
 2:  Stevadora Nicks   WG95          95
 3:     Fred Murcury    W88          88
```

If only it were always that simple.
The problem is, the degree strings only sometimes look like the above.  More often, they look like this:

```
srcDT<- data.table(
  alum=c("Ringo Harrison","Brian Wilson","Mike Jackson"),
  degree=c("W72 C73","WG95 L95","W88 WG90")
)
```

I am only interested in the 2 numbers next to the characters I care about: W & WG (and if both W and WG are there, I only care about WG)

Here's how I solved it:

```
x <-srcDT$degree                     ##grab just the degree column
z <-character()                       ## create an empty character vector
degree.grep.pattern <-c("WG[0-9][0-9]","W[0-9][0-9]")
                                     ## define a vector of regex's, in the order
                                     ## I want them

for(i in 1:length(x)){               ## loop thru all elements in degree column
  matched=F                          ## at the start of the loop, reset flag to F
  for(j in 1:length(degree.grep.pattern)){
                                     ## loop thru all elements of the pattern vector

    if(length(grep(degree.grep.pattern[j],x[i]))>0){
                                     ## see if you get a match

      m <- regexpr(degree.grep.pattern[j],x[i])
                                     ## if you do, great! grab the index of the match
      y<-regmatches(x[i],m)          ## then subset down.  y will equal "WG95"
      matched=T                      ## set the flag to T
      break                          ## stop looping
    }
                                     ## if no match, go on to next element in pattern vector
  }

  if(matched){                       ## after finishing the loop, check if you got a match
    yr <- substr(y,nchar(y)-1,nchar(y))
                                     ## if yes, then grab the last 2 characters of it
  }else{
    #if you run thru the whole list and don't match any pattern at all, just
    # take the last two characters from the affilitation
    yr <- substr(x[i],nchar(as.character(x[i]))-1,nchar(as.character(x[i])))
  }
  z<-c(z,yr)                         ## add this result (95) to the character vector
}
srcDT$degree_year<-z                ## set the column to the results.

> srcDT
             alum   degree degree_year
1: Ringo Harrison  W72 C73          72
2:   Brian Wilson WG95 L95          95
3:   Mike Jackson W88 WG90          90
```

This works.  100% of the time.  No errors, no mis-matches.
The problem is: it doesn't scale.  Given a data table with 10k rows, or 100k rows, it really slows down.

Is there a smarter, better way to do this?  This solution is very "C" to me.  Not very "R."

Thoughts on improvement?

Note: I gave a simplified example.  In the actual data, there are about 30 different possible combinations of degrees, and combined with different years, there are something like 540 unique combinations of degree strings.
Also, I gave the degree.grep.pattern with only 2 patterns to match.  In the actual work I'm doing, there are 7 or 8 patterns to match.

Comment: I presume you want `WG` because it's more recent? Would a degree awarded in 2001 be `W01`? Does every `alum` have the same number of degrees (no, I assume)?

Answer (score 5):

As it seem (per OPs) comments, there is no situation of `"WG W"`, then a simple regex solution should do the job

```
srcDT[ , degree_year := gsub(".*WG?(\\d+).*", "\\1", degree)]
srcDT
#              alum   degree degree_year
# 1: Ringo Harrison  W72 C73          72
# 2:   Brian Wilson WG95 L95          95
# 3:   Mike Jackson W88 WG90          90
```

Comment: I think `"[^S]*W[^0-9]*(\\d+).*"` fits all of the restrictions described by OP in comments on mine

Comment: @MichaelChirico yeah I already thought of a similar solution but it won't work for something like `"SW87 WG45"`. I think OP should describe all of his restrictions and possible combinations as I'm not familiar with what can or can't happen.

Comment: Agreed. @BenAdams could you edit your sample `srcDT` to something that incorporates _all_ relevant cases?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution based on the assumption that want the most recent degree with `W` in it:

```
regex <- "(?<=W|(?<=W)G)[0-9]{2}"

srcDT[ , degree_year := 
         sapply(regmatches(degree, 
                           gregexpr(regex, degree, perl = TRUE)),
                function(x) max(as.integer(x)))]

> srcDT
             alum   degree degree_year
1: Ringo Harrison  W72 C73          72
2:   Brian Wilson WG95 L95          95
3:   Mike Jackson W88 WG90          90
```

You said:

> I gave the `degree.grep.pattern` with only 2 patterns to match. In the actual work I'm doing, there are 7 or 8 patterns to match.

But I'm not sure what this means. There are more options besides `W` and `WG`?

Comment: This is beautiful.  really nice.  however, you're right.  there are other options besides `W` and `WG` , there's `GRW` and `WAM`... and most importantly there are a few `SW` that I **don't** want to match.  And a very few, a slight handful, that don't match any pattern at all.   How would you change this code to account for those?

Comment: Hmm, why not just `srcDT[ , degree_year := gsub(".*((?<=W|(?<=W)G)[0-9]{2}).*", "\\1", degree, perl = TRUE)]` if you already at it? BTW, this will fail for `"WG88 W90"`.

Comment: And you could achieve the same with just `srcDT[ , degree_year := gsub(".*WG?(\\d+).*", "\\1", degree)]` (without `perl`) but it also fails for `"WG88 W90"`

Comment: @DavidArenburg I am (trying to) use some real-world information -- namely, "G" means "graduate degree" so it's unlikely that `"WG88 W90"` exists in the data. Thanks for the suggestion of `gsub`, I'll edit that in.

Comment: @MichaelChirico you got it.  The `G` does mean _graduate degree_

Comment: If there is no case of `"WG88 W90"` possible, than I'm posting this myself as I thought of this solution about 14 hours ago and just was banging my head regarding the `"WG88 W90"` case.

Comment: @DavidArenburg fair enough! I'm priviliged to be at the same institution so I recognized the degree codes right away ;-) -- note, however, the case of `"SW87"` and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one quick hack:

```
# split all words from degree and order so that WG is before W
words <- lapply(strsplit(srcDT$degree, " "), sort, decreasing=TRUE)

# obtain tags for each row (getting only first. But works since ordered)
tags <- mapply(Find, list(function(x) grepl("^WG|^W", x)), words)

# simple gsub to remove WG and W
(result <- gsub("^WG|^W", "", tags))
[1] "72" "95" "90"
```

Fast with 100k rows.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without regular expressions, it's quite slow as it creates a sparse table... but it's clean and flexible so i leave it here.

First I split the degreeyears by space, then browse through them and build a clean structured table with one column per degree, that i fill it with years.

```
degreeyear_split <- sapply(srcDT$degree,strsplit," ") 
for(i in 1:nrow(srcDT)){
  for (degree_year in degreeyear_split[[i]]){
    n <- nchar(degree_year)
    degree <- substr(degree_year,1,n-2)
    year <- substr(degree_year,n-1,n)
    srcDT[i,degree] <- year  
  }}
```

Here I have my structure table, I paste W on the year i'm interested in, then paste WG on top of it.

```
srcDT$year <- srcDT$W
srcDT$year[srcDT$WG!=""]<-srcDT$WG[srcDT$WG!=""]
```

Then here's you result:

```
srcDT
             alum   degree  W  C WG  L year
1: Ringo Harrison  W72 C73 72 73         72
2:   Brian Wilson WG95 L95       95 95   95
3:   Mike Jackson W88 WG90 88    90      90
```